vscode map remote path to local when view log files
For example log files from server looks like this:
[2024-09-19 10:23:15,684][INFO][root][/remote/server/path/code.py:]...

When I aim mouse on path in vscode, its trying to find this source file on my local machine. Is there any way to tell vscode, that it should replace /remote/server/path to /local/path before trying to open file ?
